I keep getting Type Mismatch, setting column type to Integer
Per suggestions, I set the columns I'm using to a Const reference.
This works as long as I don't declare a column as an Integer or Long. Integer or Long returns a "compile Error, type mismatch."
When I comment out any Integer or Long columns (Plt_PltNum, Proj_1stPlate, and Proj_LastPlate) and just reference the range in the loop, the code does run, although it does not return the information I need.
I suspect that VB isn't treating the integer columns as integers, hence the >= and <= conditions don't really work.
Sub ProjectPlateLoops()

    'define workbooks and worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, PlateSheet As Worksheet, ProjSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pltNum As Integer
    Dim lrProj As Long, lrPlate As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Farm As String, Batch As String
    Dim projcode
    Dim pltprojcode
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook?
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set PlateSheet = wb.Worksheets("Plate_Analysis")
    Set ProjSheet = wb.Worksheets("Project_Analysis")
    
    'last rows in Project Analysis/Plate sheets (call separate function for this)
    lrProj = LastOccupiedRow(ProjSheet)
    lrPlate = LastOccupiedRow(PlateSheet)
    
    'column constants
    ' Plate Sheet
    'Const Plt_PltNum As Long = "E" ' plate number on PltSheet
    Const Plt_ProjID_Col As String = "F" ' proj code on PltSheet
    Const Plt_Batch_Col As String = "G" ' batch on PltSheet
    Const Plt_Farm_Col As String = "H" ' farm name on PltShee
    ' Proj Sheet
    Const Proj_ProjID_Col As String = "F" ' proj code on ProjSheet
    Const Proj_Farm_Col As String = "D" ' farm name on ProjSheet
    Const Proj_Batch_Col As String = "E" ' batch on ProjSheet
    'Const Proj_1stPlate As Integer = "J" ' first plate # in batch from ProjSheet
    'Const Proj_LastPlate As Integer = "L" ' last plate # in batch from ProjSheet

    
    ' Create Loop; if 3 conditions are met, then print Batch and Farm from Project sheet to Plate sheet
    ' Condition 1: pltprojcode = projcode
    ' Condition 2 & 3: pltNum >= firstplatenum AND <= lastplatenum
    For i = 3 To lrPlate
        pltprojcode = PlateSheet.Cells(i, Plt_ProjID_Col).Value2
          Debug.Print "i: " & (i) & ", " & "Plate ProjCode from PlateSheet: " & (pltprojcode)
        pltNum = PlateSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value2
          Debug.Print "i: " & (i) & ", " & "Plate Number from PlateSheet: " & (pltNum)
        For j = 3 To lrProj
            If ProjSheet.Cells(j, Proj_ProjID_Col).Value2 = pltprojcode Then
            projcode = ProjSheet.Cells(j, Proj_ProjID_Col).Value2
                Debug.Print "ProjCode from ProjSheet: "; j & ", " & (projcode)
              Farm = ProjSheet.Cells(j, Proj_Farm_Col).Value2
                Debug.Print "j: " & (j) & ", " & "Farm: " & (Farm)
              Batch = ProjSheet.Cells(j, Proj_Batch_Col).Value2
                Debug.Print "j: " & (j) & ", " & "Batch: " & (Batch)
              On Error Resume Next
              End If
                If pltNum >= ProjSheet.Cells(i, "J").Value2 And _
                pltNum <= ProjSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value2 Then
                PlateSheet.Cells(i, Plt_Farm_Col).Value2 = Farm 'farm
                PlateSheet.Cells(i, Plt_Batch_Col).Value2 = Batch 'batch
            On Error Resume Next
           End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function

Interestingly, if I run the code now, the only Debug.Print values that show up are in the "i" loop. If I comment out the i loop Debug.Print, the "j" debug values will print, but only the same lines over and over again, as if only one line of data actually matches all the criteria.

Const Plt_PltNum As Long = "E" - you can't assign a string value to a numerically-typed variable.   The Const variable type doesn't refer to the type of value contained in the column, but to the column letter itself, and they are all String

Using On Error Resume Next means it's very difficult to spot any errors in your code - I would comment that out.

A VBA Lookup
A Quick Fix
Sub RetrieveBatchAndFarm()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Project_Analysis"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 3
    Const SRC_PROJ_ID As String = "F" ' 2. ... here, if found...
    Const SRC_MIN_PLATE As String = "J" ' 4. ... is between...
    Const SRC_MAX_PLATE As String = "L" ' 5. ... these two, if so...
    Const SRC_BATCH As String = "E" ' 6. ... and copy this...
    Const SRC_FARM As String = "D" ' 8. ... then copy this...
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Plate_Analysis"
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 3
    Const DST_PROJ_ID As String = "F" ' 1. Find this...
    Const DST_PLATE As String = "E" ' 3. ... then check if this...
    Const DST_BATCH As String = "G" ' 7. ... here,...
    Const DST_FARM As String = "H" ' 9. ... here.
    
    ' Reference the workbook and worksheets, and determine the last rows.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim sLastRow As Long: sLastRow = GetLastRow(sws)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dLastRow As Long: dLastRow = GetLastRow(dws)
    
    ' Loop: if 'ProcId's are equal then if 'Plate' is between 'Plates'
    ' then copy 'Batch' and 'Farm'.
    
    Dim sr As Long, sFarm As String, sBatch As String, sProcId As String
    Dim dr As Long, dPlate As Double, dProcId As String
    
    For dr = DST_FIRST_ROW To dLastRow
        dProcId = CStr(dws.Cells(dr, DST_PROJ_ID).Value)
        For sr = SRC_FIRST_ROW To sLastRow
            sProcId = CStr(sws.Cells(sr, SRC_PROJ_ID).Value)
            If StrComp(sProcId, dProcId, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
                dPlate = dws.Cells(dr, DST_PLATE).Value
                If dPlate >= sws.Cells(sr, SRC_MIN_PLATE).Value _
                        And dPlate <= sws.Cells(sr, SRC_MAX_PLATE).Value Then
                    sBatch = sws.Cells(sr, SRC_BATCH).Value
                    sFarm = sws.Cells(sr, SRC_FARM).Value
                    dws.Cells(dr, DST_BATCH).Value = sBatch
                    dws.Cells(dr, DST_FARM).Value = sFarm
                    Exit For
                End If
           End If
        Next sr
    Next dr
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Batch and Farm retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub

Function GetLastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then GetLastRow = rg.Row
End Function


Hmm, it does run and retrieve data, but it only fills the first row, nothing after that. I wonder if I need to take a different approach in my loop. Maybe a Do While >= and <= first and last plate #

Sorry, my bad. I used dr (instead of sr) with sws for the source plate numbers. It's fixed now!

Thank you so much! This will save me so much time and it works quickly.
